# Calculate difference and then average per category

Tags: powerbi, dax

So here are the FACT tables:

| Purchase_ID | Purchase_Date | Supplier_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16.01.2023 | a4 |
| 2 | 18.01.2023 | a8 |
| 3 | 20.01.2023 | a8 |

| Purchase_ID | Supply_Date | Supplier_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19.01.2023 | a4 |
| 2 | 23.01.2023 | a8 |
| 3 | 27.01.2023 | a8 |

And here is the dim table for the suppliers:

| Supplier_ID | Supplier_Name |
| --- | --- |
| a4 | Example_Name_1 |
| a8 | Example_Name_2 |

I added a measure to my measures table to calculate the difference between the supply and purchase date like this:
TimeDiff = DATEDIFF(max('Purchase'[Purchase_Date]),max(Supply[Supply_Date]),DAY)
Now i want to have the average TimeDiff for every supplier and use visuals to choose a supplier and than see in other visuals the average TimeDiff for this supplier and so on.
So my questions:

1. Is the calculation of the measure correct like this (the rownumbers can change between the tables).
2. Is it possible to filter the suppliers and than calculate the average of the timediff?

Thanks for any help provided.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can each PurchaseID have exactly one Purchase Date and exactly one Supply Date? If so, your table should be (PurchaseID, PurchaseDate, SupplierID, SupplyDate) and likely something like UnitPrice and Quantity.
then your date difference is really simple like DATEDIFF(day,[PurchaseDate],[SupplyDate]). If you want to use the number of days in a pivot table (or group by them), you have to create a calculated column.

```
Average lag = 
AVERAGEX('PS Fact',
   DATEDIFF(day,[SupplyDate],[PurchaseDate])
)
```

Then you put that [Average Lag] measure in a matrix with Category on the axis and you should be sorted.

Comment: Thanks you very much Pieter. As i understand, i create a new table (from the fact tables that i have from the "raw" data and than calculate from the new table.

Comment: No, you just create a measure. you don't create any new tables.